# Convert my SQL into Typeorm query builder

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

```
SELECT DATE(OrderDate) AS date, COUNT(OrderId), ShipperID
FROM [Orders]
GROUP BY DATE(OrderDate), ShipperID
Order By Date(OrderDate) desc
```

I can't pass two parameters to groupBy() method in queryBuilder.
Is there other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getRepository(Orders)
  .createQueryBuilder('o')
  .select(['Date(o.OrderDate)','o.ShipperID', 'Count(o.OrderID)']) 
  .groupBy('Date(o.OrderDate), o.ShipperID')
  .orderBy('Date(o.OrderDate)', 'DESC')
  .getRawMany()
```